# Ionic 3: How to stop a function until cordova.window.exec is available?

Tags: angular, cordova, rxjs, observable, ionic3

I have a function which generates its return value by `window.cordova.exec`, which often initializes much later than the app. Therefore at random times the app crashes as a non-existent method is called.

What is the correct way to have the function stop and retry infinitely until `window.cordova.exec` finally responds? I am sure it can be achieved with Observables.

```
getFreeSpace() {

    return Observable.create(observer => {
        window['cordova'].exec(
            result => { 
                observer.next(result * 1024);
                observer.complete(); 
            },
            error => {
                observer.error(error)
            },
            'File',
            'getFreeDiskSpace',
            []);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using RxJs so yay!  It just means creating an observable that returns the cordova object.  This observable will poll until the object is available, then it will return it.  You can then use `switchMap` to "link" your observable(s) that needs it:

```
const POLL_INTERVAL = 1000;
const cordova$ = Observable
                   // check immediately, then every interval
                   .interval(0, POLL_INTERVAL)
                   // get the current value (or undefined)
                   .map(() => window.cordova)
                   // stop when the value is finally defined
                   .first(c => !!c);
```

Now you can define any of your cordova observables by using `switchMap` to compose them with this:

```
getFreeSpace() {
    // use cordova$ to wait for the cordova variable, then use it
    // to do our work.
    return cordova$
             .switchMap(cordova => Observable.create(observer => {
                cordova.exec(
                  result => { 
                    observer.next(result * 1024);
                    observer.complete(); 
                  },
                  error => {
                    observer.error(error)
                  },
                  'File',
                  'getFreeDiskSpace',
                  []);
             }));
}
```

Comment: Correction: I am already fumbling with rxjs like an idiot. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait the device ready event before call any cordova function.. 
"deviceready" event will be triggered after all cordova plugin has been initialized and declared..

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", firstInitCordova, true);
};

function firstInitCordova(){
    if(!window.cordova.exec){
        // If exec is not defined then call this function again after 2 second
        setTimeout(firstInitCordova, 2000);
        return;
    }
    getFreeSpace();
    // Another startup function like retrieving database or getting network info
}

// If you're unsure then set a timer
setTimeout(function(){
    firstInitCordova();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: That I know, but Ionic (Angular) doesn't wait.